# CSS transition affects two classes instead of one

Tags: angularjs, css, css-transitions

I have built a HTML page which displays a quote of some person. I want to create an effect where author name fades in first, and then after a second fades in the quote.

I have achieved my goal, but I am having an issue. Everytime I set `transition-delay` on the quote element, the author element gets delayed as well. That makes that the author is faded in T+1s, and the quote in T+2s. In reality, it's not T+1s and T+2s, but more.

Here is the code that reproduces my problem: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MqYpipM7H6GUyhtVfrPW?p=preview)

When you click on "Toggle show" button, then the quote appears. You can notice, that the text fades in after a few seconds. However, if you delete `.quote-text` from CSS, you will notice that the text fades in almost immediately.

My question is, why `transition-delay` set on class `.quote-text` affect transition that is set on class `.quote-author`? How can I eliminate that affection?

Thank you for your time

Comment: Can you simply tell me what you're exactly trying to do in steps, thank you.

Comment: Yea please explain a bit more, having a hard time understanding your problem

Comment: Thank you for your time Gentlemen. I am trying to create an effect where the author node fades in T+0s, and then the quote node in T+1s. Currently, I am receiving a huge delay at the beginning. With my code, it looks more like T+4s for the author and T+5s for the quote.

Comment: One more clarification. T+0s and T+1s means where the fade in process begins, not the duration of the fade effect (which for both elements should be 0.5s).

Comment: One more thing. The animation must work with `ng-animate` and `ng-show` from Angular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I didn't want to answer this because I only have very basic idea on how AngularJS works. But I tried something that might help a bit. The downside is that I removed ng-animate and added ng-class, which doesn't satisfy your question. But I believe you can somehow substitute it with ng-animate, again, this is only to help and might give you some idea.

Check this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xGb8r6QQ0RJbmHajaSPx?p=preview)

I only changed css and this two lines in html:

```
<h2 class="quote-author transition" ng-class="{'show-me': show}">Bill Nye</h2>
<span class="quote-text transition" ng-class="{'show-me': show}">&ldquo;Everyone you ever meet knows something you don’t&rdquo;</span>
```

Comment: Your answer has helped to fix my problem, thank you very much!